# Using Pageant or KeeAgent with Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows-10, ssh, keepass

I've recently started using LXSS, or "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows", and having used Cygwin before I could use ssh from terminal and authenticate with Putty Pageant (or Keepass KeeAgent) . How can I achieve this with ssh inside the Bash terminal?

Answer (score 0):

weasel-pageant is made for this purpose, available at https://github.com/vuori/weasel-pageant.

I extracted it into C:\Program Files\weasel-pageant-1.1, then added the following to .bashrc:

```
if [ -x /mnt/c/Program\ Files/weasel-pageant-1.1/weasel-pageant ]; then
    eval $(/mnt/c/Program\ Files/weasel-pageant-1.1/weasel-pageant -ra ~/.weasel-pageant)
fi
```